# How do I format the date in Event Organizer?

Tags: formatting

I would like to format the dates to be June 17, 2012 11:00am as opposed to the 17 June 2012 11:00am that [Event Organizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) outputs.

Comment: close voted as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

`%start{date-format}{time-format}%` ([using php date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) for example:

```
%start{M jS, Y}{ g:i:a}%*
```

This will output as June 17, 2012 11:00am

Shortcode: `[eo_events]<a href="%event_url%">%event_title%</a> on %start{M jS, Y}{ g:i:a}%, at %event_venue%[/eo_events]`

Referance: [Event Organiser](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/event-organiser/documentation/shortcodes/event-list-shortcode/)